# Htaccess for subdomain using Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Can you help me with htaccess for sub domain using codeigniter.

In my localhost I have this htaccess that is working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now if I move my files in my subdomain.sample.com, What should I write in my htaccess ?

Comment: When trying to use my htaccess and rename the foldername, my css is not working and also for calling the pages. Anybody can help me with this ?

Comment: Did you yupdate you `base_url` variable in the config file?

Comment: My config file . $config['base_url'] = '';

Do I have to put my subdomain address there ?

By the way, this is how I call my css file: 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>" media="all"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Config.php**

```
# Localhost
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Appsite/website/';
# Live
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.sample.com/'; // if secured site use https
# Subdomain 
$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.sample.com/';// if secured site use https
```

**To accessing URL**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('contollerName/methodName');?>"> click here</a>
```

**To access image**

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/images.PNG');?>”>
```

**To access css**

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**To access js**

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/some_js.js');?>"></script>
```

Comment: Do I need to change my htaccess file ?

Comment: Thanks man . But my problem now is when accessing my admin page, it says 404 not found . (eg. http://subdomain.sample.com/admin). Can you help me with this too. Much appreciated

Comment: for admin, you have separate Core & application(controller,config,model etc) folder? if yes, update that config file too ex, `$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.sample.com/admin/';`

Comment: I only have Controller and model separated.

Comment: Then, you need to define new config variable and use it. ex, `$config['admin_base_url']='http://subdomain.sample.com/admin/';`


In admin (all) Controller's constructor function, load config like `$this->admin_config = $this->config->item('admin_base_url'); `


Then you can call `$this->admin_config['admin_base_url']` anywhere in the controller and it's view(s).

Comment: Still 404 not found. I already follow what you said. I already put $config['dashboard_base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.sample.com/dashboard'; in my config file and also in my controller public function __construct(){$this->dashboard_config = $this->config->item('dashboard_base_url');}